# convert a list of lists to a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list looks like this:

```
mylist = [['I','have','an','apple'],['she','have','an','orange']]
```

and I want each list contained in mylist should be a row in the dataframe and the dataframe should look like this:

```
          text
'I','have','an','apple'
'she','have','an','orange'
```

I tried to convert it but it shows a results like this:

```
 0        1      2       3
'I'    'have'   'an'  'apple'
'she'  'have'   'an'  'orange'
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

*NB. do **not** use `list` as a variable, this overwrites the python builtin*

##### DataFrame constructor

You can use a dictionary in the DataFrame constructor:

```
lst = [['I','have','an','apple'],['she','have','an','orange']]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': lst})
```

output:

```
                      name
0     [I, have, an, apple]
1  [she, have, an, orange]
```

##### Series constructor

Alternatively, use a Series that you convert to frame:

```
df = pd.Series(lst, name='text').to_frame()
```

##### manually reshaping input for the DataFrame constructor

Or manually wrap each list in a sublist to avoid expansion to columns:

```
lst = [['I','have','an','apple'],['she','have','an','orange']]
df = pd.DataFrame([[e] for e in lst])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a super simple way to do this by only using `pd.DataFrame` -

```
mylist = [['I','have','an','apple'],['she','have','an','orange']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'text':mylist})
print(df)
```

```
                      text
0     [I, have, an, apple]
1  [she, have, an, orange]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `agg`:

```
>>> df.agg(list, axis=1)
0       [I, have, an, apple]
1    [she, have, an, orange]
dtype: object
>>>
```

To a `DataFrame`:

```
>>> df.agg(list, axis=1).to_frame('text')
                      text
0     [I, have, an, apple]
1  [she, have, an, orange]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
lst = [['I','have','an','apple'],['she','have','an','orange']]
df = pd.Series(lst, name='text').apply(lambda x: ', '.join(f"'{a}'" for a in x)).to_frame()
```

Output:

```
                            text
0     'I', 'have', 'an', 'apple'
1  'she', 'have', 'an', 'orange'
```